# PHP: Return only one property from object

Tags: php, wordpress, object

I have this code on a Woocommerce site, which successfully returns the entire responded object:

```
function checkProducts($data) {
    $product_ID = $data['id'];
    $api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://whatever.net/wc-api/v3/products/'.$product_ID, array(
        'method'    => 'GET',
        'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'key:secret' )
        )
    ) );

    $body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );

    if( wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $api_response ) === 'OK' ) {
        return $body;
    }
}
```

I have tried to only return the `stock_quantity` property in many ways, which is present on the object, with no success, among others:

```
$body = json_decode( $api_response['body']['stock_quantity'] );
return $body['stock_quantity']:
return $body.stock_quantity;
```

JSON returned:

```
{
product: {
id: 687,
created_at: "2019-10-08T10:21:57Z",
updated_at: "2019-10-08T13:53:32Z",
type: "simple",
status: "publish",
downloadable: false,
virtual: false,
permalink: "https://germanalvarez.net/develop/ww/producto/tww-fin-de-semana-del-3-al-4/",
sku: "",
price: "200",
stock_quantity: "200",
sale_price: "120",
...
```

How could I archive this? Thank you

Comment: What does `var_dump($body);` give you? Sounds like `$body->stock_quantity` should work but impossible to tell without seeing the data structure

Comment: Also, what are the _many ways_ and did it generate an error/notice?

Comment: Did you just skip over @BrettGregson comment?

Comment: I have just added your info and I am looking for the response for @BrettGregson, would you please give me a minute? Thank you.

Comment: @BrettGregson, tried your example with no success, just returns null. I am facing problems with the var_dump() as I can not see it's result, I am quite unexperienced with this, sorry. I have edited adding final JSON that is returned to front

Comment: Thanks for the mark @AbraCadaver, just learned how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - `json_decode` will return an object by default:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php


Try the following:

```
$body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );
$stock_quantity = $body->product->stock_quantity;
return $stock_quantity;
```

If however you want to operate on an array, here's the way to do it (notice second parameter in `json_decode`):

```
$body = json_decode( $api_response['body'], true );
$stock_quantity = $body['product']['stock_quantity'];
return $stock_quantity;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid this does not match returned structure. Could you check my question edit? There you'll see the JSON

Comment: I've updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you Lukasz, solved :)